# How can I reach distant systems

Tags: elite-dangerous

When I want to travel to a system very far away from my current location, so that I can't simply reach it using the planner in the galaxy map, what is the best way to do that?

Do I have to move and rotate the galaxy map so that I can figure out what reachable star system is the closest and this way make my way to the target - that way I would never know if I can reach the system at all until I end up in a place that's too far away for a jump to the next system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route planner now(since update 1.1) will path up to 1000LY away, and you don't need to wait for it to path before selecting.

Just select the star you wish to travel to and if it is within 1000LY you can click the plan route button and it will set one up for you quickly.

The automatic route planner still takes a decently long time to build a web, though.

If the line that appears is solid you can make it there in a single tank. if the path becomes a dotted line, you will need to stop and refuel or scoop some fuel to keep going.

There are some [tools](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=82832) people use to speed up the searching, but as with any third party app. Use at your own risk/discretion.

Comment: I've found that the in-game route planner rarely goes beyond 70LY and never beyond 100LY.

Comment: the wait just gets exponentially longer the farther you want to go. I've just left it open while watching youtubes and stuff to go 200+ LY journeys

Comment: This answer is wrong. The game currently does not route beyond 100Ly. (unless something has changed recently?)

Comment: @SimonW the game just updated which increased the route planner to 1000LY

Answer (score 4):

I personally never bother with the 3rd party tools.  They don't contain information about every star system in the game and there is no guarantee of accuracy of the information that they do contain.

I always do as you suggest - rotating the map around the destination so that I can see the marker for my current location (if you "lock on" to the desired destination you can use the little arrow buttons next to the destination and your current location to swap between them, giving you hints to the direction).

Once the spider web of routes has expanded out to the maximum range (currently about 100Ly), I choose a point on it that appears to be going in the correct direction.  This system is clumsy, slow, and frankly not very good, but at least it doesn't involve Alt-Tabbing out to 3rd party tools.

Soon (within this month, according to their announcements), Frontier are launching an update which among other things will extend route planning out to 1000Ly, so this should alleviate the problem.  Hopefully this range extension will not be a simple adjustment of the current route planning max distance parameter - hopefully better optimised path finding code has made this extension practical.

Personally I don't understand the need for the game to plan out every possible route from your current location.  Like the original Elite, it could simply give an indication of how far you can travel in a single jump and leave it to the player to trigger the route planning - when they select a system as the destination, no matter how far away it is, the game should then plan the route to that system.  It should be a lot faster, a lot less cluttered and a lot more useful.

Comment: I imagine that the 1000Ly planner may work on-demand towards a specific system, rather than finding every possible path from the current location. I'm speculating, though.

Comment: I can update my answer: Definitely wait for v1.1 to go live. I've tried the Beta and the route planning is massively improved in terms of usability and speed.  The initial web still calculates, but it appears to be a lot faster than before.  In addition to this, you can now select Route Finding on systems way out of the range of the web and you get a little "busy" spinner while the route is calculated, which in the cases I tried usually took less than a second.

Comment: Ooh, shiny! I don't have beta access, but as somebody currently 1200ly from Sol, I look forward to this :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of online third-party routing tools that you can use to find your way on long voyages.

[CMDR's Club](https://cmdr.club/routes/) is the one that I use, although [Elite Dangerous Central](http://www.elitedangerouscentral.com/) is another one that's fairly popular. Note that these tools may not work for distant, less-frequented star systems.

Answer (score 1):

One technique that can help a little is as follows:

1. Click on the target system (at whatever distance), and select it to put a marker on it.
2. Zoom out until you can see both your current location (blue marker) and the destination (orange marker). Your view should still be centred on the destination.
3. Zoom in *slowly* until your current position disappears behind your viewpoint, and hover the mouse over stars in the foreground until you find one at a little under 100Ly distance.
4. Wait, if necessary, for the blue route network to reach to the star you are looking at. Ask the game for a route to this star. Repeat after 100Ly.

I've found that this method is helpful for travelling up to ~500Ly. Beyond that it may get too difficult to operate. It won't help to route around large sparse areas where you may have to backtrack for more than 100Ly.